# Why are the Tyrells so hung up on the battle of Ashford?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Is that their only achievement besides being selected by Aegon the conqueror to be the Lords Paramount of the Mander and the liege lords of the Reach?

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes sense grammatically. I don't watch the show, but it still seems like this is missing words or something. The title seems okay, but I don't know what the question itself is asking.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Let me rephrase my question. If you had a gun held to your head, and you were asked: "what were the achievements of house Tyrell, besides being Lords Paramount of the Mander and the liege lords of the Reach?" what would be your answer. English grammar is not my strongest side, that is true